# Application Insights URL Ping test - do the GUIDs actually need to be unique?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

When creating an Application Insights [URL ping test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability) programmatically, for instance via Terraform or the REST API, there are at least two GUID fields. In all examples I have seen, those seem to be using random but static values.

So my question is: In what scope do those actually need to be unique? Can I, for example, create the same URL test in two different Application Insights instances with exactly the same XML definition?

So I'm talking about `Id="zzzzzzzz-zzzzzz-zzzz-zzzzzz"` and `Guid="xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx"`:

```xml
<WebTest Name="appinsights-webtest1" Id="zzzzzzzz-zzzzzz-zzzz-zzzzzz" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" Timeout="30" WorkItemIds="" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010" Description="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword="" PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="default" StopOnError="False" RecordedResultFile="" ResultsLocale="">
  <Items>
    <Request Method="GET" Guid="xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx" Version="1.1" Url="https://example.com" ThinkTime="0" Timeout="30" ParseDependentRequests="False" FollowRedirects="False" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8" ExpectedHttpStatusCode="200" ExpectedResponseUrl="" ReportingName="" IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False" />
  </Items>
</WebTest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently URL Ping still uses Visual Studio Test Agent (deprecated as of March 2019) to run these tests. As a result it expects a test in their format. Application Insights Availability service ignores these values. You can put any GUIDs there.

PS: We are about to release a Public Preview for a new modernized SKU. API for this SKU will be more streamlined and will not require composing a test in proprietary xml format.

Comment: thanks for your reply! Looking forward to the new SKU :)